# putting a semi-transparent div over a highcharts graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

is it possible to put a div over a generated highcharts graph? As in, a div with a transparent background that will have text in it for purely aesthetic purposes.

Being able to select the chart isn't important -- just seeing it.

Comment: I don't see anything in your code indicating that it can't be done

Comment: Would be great if you provide some sample code. But the answer is yes, one way will be to relatively position the graph container and have an absolutely positioned child div in the container with proper z-index and the properties that you want.

Answer (score 1):

Doing what you want can be done in CSS alone.

As was mentioned in a comment, you want to have a `relative` container, and then `absolute` position the elements within it.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
    <div class="overlayed"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    position: relative;
}
div.overlayed, canvas {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

*I just used a sample canvas element to give an idea of where your chart would be.*

**[Here's a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/enigmarm/47fpW/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

Add div positioned absolutely with higher z-index than Highcharts chart. See: http://jsfiddle.net/Ww5Tg/9/

```
<div class="over"></div>
<div id="container" style="height: 300px; width: 400px"></div>
```

And CSS:

```
.over {
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0.2;    
}
```